# Why do I get access violation run-time error?

Tags: c++, arrays, iteration, runtime-error

I want to iterate diagonally over a two dimensional array. I use a normal array with `[N*N]` size instead of using an `[N][N]` array. After that, I produce the indexes.
This is the array I want to print (for example)

```
1 3 6 10
2 5 9 13
4 8 12 15
7 11 14 16
```

the result should be like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
```

I've done with the following code:

```
int n, temp[2], nums[100 + 10];
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
    cin >> nums[i];

temp[0] = temp[1] = 0;
for (int i = 0, cnt = 0; i < n; i++, cnt += 5) {
    temp[1] = temp[0];
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        cout << nums[temp[1]] << " ";
        temp[1] -= n - 1;
    }
    temp[0] += n;
}

temp[0] -= n - 1;
for (int i = n - 2, cnt = temp[0]; i >= 0; i--, cnt -= 5) {
    temp[1] = temp[0];
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        cout << nums[temp[1]] << " ";
        temp[1] -= n - 1;
    }
    temp[0] += 1;
}
```

I think it should work, but I don't know why I get access violation run-time error.
Thanks.

Comment: Where does the access violation occur?

Comment: @RaymondChen unfortunately I don't know! It's an ACM problem and the website tells me that you have access violation on test-case #4 and I don't know what is the test case. this is the link of the problem:
http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1313

Comment: It works here http://ideone.com/eW1Yrx with your input

Comment: @SergiiKhaperskov thanks. I know it works but the problem just occurs on some specific test-cases. (Please read the commnet above)

Comment: Um, isn't asking for outside help with a contest kind of cheating? "It is forbidden to share source codes or solution ideas with another participants. Violation of this rule will result in disqualification." Posting the source code to a public web site seems to fit the category of "sharing source codes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your link `1 ≤ N ≤ 100` which means `nums` array should be able to store up to 100*100=10000 values.

Answer (score 1):

Anyways:
the site states 1 <= N <= **100** which means the largest possible array you will need is
`max(N*N)` which is 10,000 integers. The code you posted has allocated the array for 110 integer elements which obviously is not enough.
The access violation might be happening during the reading of input numbers in the first for loop because `i` goes to `n*n` which might be larger than the size of your array.

Comment: I wanted to accept your answer, but someone answer a little bit sooner than you. +10 reputation is good too! :D Thanks anyway buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all my friend, which compiler are you using?
if borland's turbo , then you may want to switch over to another one because this is a common error in that as i have experienced .
your code seems to be correct and by executing the same code(copy-pasting) in Code::Blocks , I got the output as you have mentioned. so, your program is correct.

Comment: I use visual c++ 2010 with code::blocks!
thanks for answering me, please read the comments above and I exactly explained my problem. Thanks ;)

Comment: "specific test-cases"  hmm.. can you mention those test cases?

Comment: Unfortunately no! because the site doesn't let me to see test-cases!
here's the link. http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1313

Comment: yeah, i have read that link. did they mention that some specific cases aren't working?